# Formatting output with device's currency settings

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm working on my first iPhone app and would love to be able to format the currency with the device's currency settings.

At present I have this:

```
- (IBAction)calculate {

    float lp = ([leftPrice.text floatValue]);
    float rp = ([rightPrice.text floatValue]);
    float lw = ([leftWeight.text floatValue]);
    float rw = ([rightWeight.text floatValue]);

    float lppkg = lp/lw;
    float rppkg = rp/rw;

    if (lp > 0 && lw > 0) {
        leftPricePerKg.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", lppkg];
    }

    if (rp > 0 && rw > 0) {
        rightPricePerKg.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$%.2f", rppkg];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check out NSNumberFormatter -

You can look here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter

And here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW1

**Especially on**

"Configuring the Format of Currency" Part

**Edit**

I found that -

```
//--------------------------------------------
// Format style as currency, output to console
//--------------------------------------------
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:[attributesDict objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize]];
NSLog(@"Output as currency: %@", formattedOutput);

//--------------------------------------------
// Change local and output as currency
//--------------------------------------------
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"it_IT"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:[attributesDict objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize]];
NSLog(@"Output as currency - locale it_IT: %@", formattedOutput);
```

Here:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/formatting-numbers-nsnumberformatter-examples.html

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the following but can't get it to work. I'm obviously missing something: currency.text = [NSString currencySymbol];